# JQuery + Display next element one by one

Tags: jquery

So, I have this HTML

```
<div id="myFields">
    <fieldset class="newSet">
        <p>
            <label for="item1">Item Name or #</label>
            <input name="item1" type="text" id="item1" size="25" maxlength="15" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>    
    <fieldset class="newSet">
        <p>
            <label for="item2">Item Name or #</label>
            <input name="item2" type="text" id="item2" size="25" maxlength="15" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>    
    <fieldset class="newSet">
        <p>
            <label for="item2">Item Name or #</label>
            <input name="item2" type="text" id="item2" size="25" maxlength="15" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>    
</div>
```

Then outside the div myFields I have an image serving as a button (with id="add").  When clicked, the next fieldset is supposed to appear, for which I have this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".newSet").hide();

            $("#add").click(function() {

            $(".newSet").next().show("slow");

            });
```

But it will not show only the next one but all of them at once.

I am sure there is a more elegant/efficient way of doing is but I cannot find it.

Thanks for the help.

Here is a jsFiddle example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/XyW4m/

Comment: Put the inputs inside the labels

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $(".newSet:hidden:first").show("slow");
});
```

"Show the [first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) [hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) `fieldset`."

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/XGDAd/

Answer (score 0):

The next of what? You could set on click to show the nth fieldset in this way i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".newSet").hide();
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $(".newSet:nth-child(1)").show("slow"); //show the first one
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to hard code the FIELDSET elements. You can just have one FIELDSET in the beginning and then clone it if the user clicks "Add".

HTML:

```
<div id="myFields">
    <fieldset>
        <label>
            Item Name or #
            <input type="text" size="25" maxlength="15">
        </label>            
    </fieldset>
</div>

<button> Add </button>
```

JavaScript:

```
var fields = $('#myFields');

$('button').click(function() {
    fields.children(':first').clone().hide().appendTo(fields).show('slow'); 
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rV9Q7/4/

Comment: Won't this generate multiple `input`s with the same `id`?